# Update multiple rows of database in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, orm

I want a code for update multiple rows of database, somthing like this:

```
UPDATE values SET data='{"options":["male","female"],"default":"male"}' where project_id=1 and id=1;
UPDATE values SET data='{"options":["male","female"],"default":"male"}' where project_id=1 and id=2;
UPDATE values SET data='{"options":["male","female"],"default":"male"}' where project_id=1 and id=3;
```

After some hours i could get result with something like this in laravel framework:

```
$values = Value::where('project_id', $id)->get();
$sql = "";
foreach($request->fields as $field) {
  if(!empty($field->default)) { //New default value is set
    foreach($values as $value) {
      $data = json_decode($value->data, true); /**data column as json object in mysql database **/
      $data["default"] = $field->default;
      $data = json_encode($data);
      $sql .= "update ".DB::connection()->getDatabaseName().".values set data='".$data."' where id="."$value->id;";
    }
  }
}
DB::unprepared($sql);
```

but this code is not a good practice!
So my question is

> Is there any ORM way to do this better?!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here is an easy way to do it.

```
$values = Value::where('project_id', $id)->update(['data'=>$data]);
```

I found it from [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#updates) link

Hope it helps.

Comment: Assuming all records should have the same values, this is the correct answer. You could change the link to the manual instead of another site.

Answer (score -6):

```
    $values = Value::where('project_id', $id)->get();
    $sql = "";
    foreach($request->fields as $field) {
      if(!empty($field->default)) { //New default value is set
        foreach($values as $value) {      
          $tmp=$value->data;
          $tmp->default = $field->default;
          $value->data = $tmp;
          $value->save();
        }
      }
    }
```

And in `Value` model use `Mutator` and `Accessor`, like this

```
public function getDataAttribute($value)
{
    return json_decode($value);
}
public function setDataAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['data'] = json_encode($value);
}
```

See documentation http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators

Work - https://yadi.sk/i/BnC3HYozehoy2

Comment: Thank you very much @vitalik_74 but there is an error: `Indirect modification of overloaded property Value::$data has no effect`

Comment: Sorry, is wrong `$this->attributes['dmm_month']`. I do copy\paste from my project :) . I change in answer to `$this->attributes['data']`

Comment: I run this code. And change. Please, see my answer and screenshort.

Comment: But still same error for me! Is there any way to save all changes once after foreach? I think this way is slow when database records are much

Comment: http://s251.uploadbaz.com/files/1/qowkoofiq580ve/Screenshot%20from%202015-02-16%2016:31:55.png

Comment: Show controller, please

Comment: http://s308.uploadbaz.com/files/7/hw7hjdtkk0xa9c/Screenshot%20from%202015-02-16%2016:44:47.png

Comment: Ok. My code and your not equal. Use `$tmp=$value->data;
          $tmp->default = $field->default;
          $value->data = $tmp;
          $value->save();`