# Update one-to-many relation in Laravel: Array to string conversion error

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent

I'm trying to update multiple rows but I face an array to string conversion error. Donation to Donation Items is a one-to-many relation and up to 5 types of items may be updated. I've already tried using solution from [Update multiple rows of database in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28539400/update-multiple-rows-of-database-in-laravel) and used the saveMany() method but I'm still not able to update the given rows.

Here's what I tried:

```
    $n = 0;
    $donationItems = DonationItems::where('donation_id', $donationId)->get();
    foreach ($donationItems as $item) {

        $itemName = $r->get('item-name');
        $itemQuantity = $r->get('item-quantity');

        $item->name = $itemName;
        $item->quantity = $itemQuantity;
        $item->donation_id = $donation->id;

        $donation->donationItems()->save($item);

        $n += 1;
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46828717/4232159

Comment: What output did you've get when you've `var_dump($item)` inside your `foreach`?

Comment: Same error when I used var_dump($item). When I tried dd($item) it gives the original value of the fields that were previously filled. In this case, I had one record of item.
  #attributes: array:6 [▼
    "id" => 3
    "name" => "wwwwwwwwwwwww"
    "quantity" => 5
    "created_at" => "2017-10-20 16:12:10"
    "updated_at" => "2017-10-20 19:27:25"
    "donation_id" => 3
  ]
  #original: array:6 [▼
    "id" => 3
    "name" => "wwwwwwwwwwwww"
    "quantity" => 5
    "created_at" => "2017-10-20 16:12:10"
    "updated_at" => "2017-10-20 19:27:25"
    "donation_id" => 3
  ]

Answer (score 0):

Change your line

```
$donation->donationItems()->save($item);
```

For

```
$item->save();
```

Since you already set the `donation_id` on your `$item`, you don't need to save them through the relation

Comment: It still gives me the array to string conversion error though.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `update()` method which will create just one query instead of N queries:

```
DonationItems::where('donation_id', $donationId)
    ->update([
        $item->name = $r->item-name;
        $item->quantity = $r->item-quantity;
        $item->donation_id = $donation->id;
    ]);
```

This will work as long as you're properly using `$fillable` array in the model:

```
protected $fillable = ['name', 'quantity', 'donation_id'];
```